# How can I complete my Omega Mechanos set?

Tags: destiny-2

I am looking to complete my [Omega Mechanos set armour](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Omega_Mechanos_Hunter_Armor_Set).

It's my understanding that Eververse has single armour pieces in a rotation which changes every weekly reset.

How can I collect this armour set? Do I need to wait and buy single pieces from Eververse?

Comment: Updated answer -- looks like you can complete your set, but it will cost silver sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck my friend! With Season of the Worthy, they have brought back the Omega Mechanos set through the Eververse store. To find it, it's in the **Archive Tab** for 1500 silver.

[image]